# Deserialise string to different types in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string which can contain different type at different times. I want to successfully parse it and pass it to the other components. Sometime it will have only one integer value, sometime it will be a dictionary of fields. These are the examples of the string i am talking about

```
   1. startOffset : {
      "test" : {
        "0" : 5127877
      }
   }

   2. startOffset : "3213213"
```

I have class to hold the startOffset

```
public class StartOffset {
    private String topic;
    private long partitionId;
    private long fromOffset;
}
```

In the second case partitionId, topic will be Null, How can I parse both string and construct StartOffset class

Comment: You could just test if the string can be parsed as an integer using regex or something, otherwise parse it as JSON.

Comment: I did write a custom library for this. I don't know if this is so helpfull, but you can take a look at it [https://git.flouet.com/flouet-base-java](https://git.flouet.com/flouet/flouet-base-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flouet/code/base/configuration/ConfigurationBuilder.java).